# Как изменить размер TextView после изменения шрифта из кода?

Tags: android

Устанавливаю FontFamily из кода и для некоторых шрифтов (c наклоном) происходит обрезка по краям т.к они не вмещаются в старые границы TextView. Пробовал делать invalidate(). Есть способ увеличить ширину после изменение шрифта?

Comment: может приведете пример xml, кода который используете чтобы текст модифицировать? без этого сложно сказать точно что и где нужно менять

Comment: Согласен, возможно разметка не позволяет ему увеличиться до нужных размеров.